# Creating a LinkedList with Nodes C++

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list, header-files, nodes

I am tasked with creating a Linked List in C++. I am supposed to create a struct for both LinkedList and Node .There are many functions I am supposed to have in this program, but for my own understanding I am justtrying to write an append function at the moment.

I have 3 files I'm using:

**hw10.h**

```
#ifndef Structures_hw10
#define Structures_hw10

#include <iostream>

struct Node{
  int value;
  Node* next;
};

struct LinkedList{
  Node* head = NULL;
};

void append(int);

#endif
```

**hw10.cpp**

```
#include "hw10.h"

void LinkedList::append(int data){
  Node* cur = head;
  Node* tmp = new Node;
  tmp->value = data;
  tmp->next = NULL;
  if(cur->next == NULL) {
    head  = tmp;
  }
  else {
    while(cur->next != NULL){
      cur = cur->next;
    }
    cur->next = tmp;
  }

  // delete cur;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "hw10.h"

int main(){
  LinkedList LL;
  LL.append(5);
  LL.append(6);
  Node* cur = LL.head;
  while(cur->next != NULL){
    std::cout<<cur->value<<std::endl;
    cur = cur->next;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

To compile this code, I type in terminal:

```
g++ -o hw10 hw10.cpp main.cpp
```

This is the response I receive:

```
 In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
hw10.h:13:16: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
In file included from hw10.cpp:1:0:
hw10.h:13:16: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
hw10.cpp: In function 'void append(int)':
hw10.cpp:10:15: error: 'head' was not declared in this scope
```

My main function is supposed to create a new Linked List and append 2 new nodes, and print their values out(to assure it worked).

Comment: The error points to use of head on line 10 in hw10.cpp, but head is on line 9 not 10 and it looks ok. This doesn't look like the exact source code that was compiled, is it?

Comment: @koodawg This is the source code I have written.

Comment: I compiled your code and get a completely different error, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Here in your struct declaration you must have append inside the struct like so;

```
struct LinkedList{
  Node* head = NULL;
  void append(int);
};
```

Try adding "-std=c++11 " to eliminate the warnings.

Comment: I believe C++11 added the ability to initialize members in a struct.